# Send http post-request when order invoiced

Tags: magento-1.9, http-request

I want **magento 1.9** to send an http post to a webhook for every invoice created.

Is there any model or easy modification to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use an observer to the `sales_order_invoice_save_after` event

Comment: I have no Idea how to use observer or to write codes in magento, I was somehow looking for a ready code where I can just change the webhook url.